# Mathematica does not recognize RegionPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I've been desperately trying to graph a 3D region fitting the following three inequalities:

```
-x <= z <= x
-y <= z <= y
(x-y)/2 <= z <= (x-y)
```

Nothing I do seems to work. I am using *Mathematica* 10.0. Using a single inequality, it appears to default to using `ContourPlot3D`, and using multiple inequalities it does not recognize it at all. I thought I might be running some old version that does not support `RegionPlot3D`, but it recognizes `RegionPlot3D` as a Wolfram Language symbol, it just won't work.

In fact, even testing it now, simply copying over the examples from the *Mathematica* `RegionPlot3D` page, they aren't recognized either. I feel like I am doing something majorly wrong, but it's been years since I used *Mathematica* and can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you on? Have you tried restarting *Mathematica*?

Comment: I don't see a problem with `RegionPlot3D` -- `RegionPlot3D[-x <= z <= x && -y <= z <= y && (x - y)/2 <= z <= (x - y), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]` produces a good looking plot

Comment: From 10.0.0: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ezkTy.png

Comment: I am obtaining a pretty similar plot to Michael E2. Once you get RegionPlot3D working, you can use PlotPoints to obtain a better looking plot. Some of the edges are initially very rough.